# performance issue in parameter initiation for stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, stored-procedures, parameters

I would like to know is there any difference for the parameter initiation of stored procedures:

when setting parameter value for a stored procedures in this way, it takes around 20 seconds to run

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[sp_SSRS_01]
@user                   Varchar(100) = '123',
@corporate              int = 123,
@contract               Varchar(2000) = '123'
```

but if i initiate the parameter in the following way, it takes 8 mins to run

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[sp_SSRS_01]
@user                   Varchar(100) = null,
@corporate              int = null,
@contract               Varchar(2000) = null

set @user = '123'
set @corporate = 123
set @contract = '123'
```

Can anyone know the difference about that?
thanks~

Comment: It might be something related to parameter sniffing. But what actually defines their values is how you call the SP in both these cases. In the first case, you can override default values, which is impossible in the second.

Comment: How are you calling the stored procedure?  Are you specifying the params, or relying on defaults?  Also, I would try dropping your SP, then re-creating it and executing it the second way (null defaults) and seeing if it creates a better plan for that method.